# Sort DataFrame based on part of its index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, lambda

### What I would like to achieve

I have a DataFrame whose indices are "ID (int) + underscore (_) + name (str)". I would like to sort the data based on the ID.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12], [13, 14]]
index = ['11_ItemName', '0_ItemName', '1_ItemName', '2_ItemName', '10_ItemName', '20_ItemName', '101_ItemName']
columns = ['column1', 'column2']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)
print(df)
## Output
#              column1  column2
# 11_ItemName        1        2
# 0_ItemName         3        4
# 1_ItemName         5        6
# 2_ItemName         7        8
# 10_ItemName        9       10
# 20_ItemName       11       12
# 101_ItemName      13       14

# print(DO SOMETHING!)
## Expected output
#              column1  column2
# 0_ItemName         3        4
# 1_ItemName         5        6
# 2_ItemName         7        8
# 10_ItemName        9       10
# 11_ItemName        1        2
# 20_ItemName       11       12
# 101_ItemName      13       14
```

### What I tested

I tried to use `sort_index` and failed.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html

To be honest, I'm stuck at the debug of `lambda`.

```
df(sort_index())
## Output
#              column1  column2
# 0_ItemName         3        4
# 101_ItemName      13       14
# 10_ItemName        9       10
# 11_ItemName        1        2
# 1_ItemName         5        6
# 20_ItemName       11       12
# 2_ItemName         7        8

print(df.sort_index(key=(lambda x: int(x.str.split('_')[0]))))
# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'list'
```

### Environment

Python 3.10.5
Pandas 1.4.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`df.sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) with custom `key=`:

```py
df = df.sort_index(
    key=lambda idx: idx.str.split("_")
    .str[0]
    .astype(int)
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
              column1  column2
0_ItemName          3        4
1_ItemName          5        6
2_ItemName          7        8
10_ItemName         9       10
11_ItemName         1        2
20_ItemName        11       12
101_ItemName       13       14
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`natsort`](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) for natural sorting:

```
# pip install natsort
from natsort import natsort_key

out = df.sort_index(key=natsort_key)
```

output:

```
              column1  column2
0_ItemName          3        4
1_ItemName          5        6
2_ItemName          7        8
10_ItemName         9       10
11_ItemName         1        2
20_ItemName        11       12
101_ItemName       13       14
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the pandas docs, the key function needs to be vectorised:

> keycallable, optional If not None, apply the key function to the index
> values before sorting. This is similar to the key argument in the
> builtin sorted() function, with the notable difference that this key
> function should be vectorized. It should expect an Index and return an
> Index of the same shape. For MultiIndex inputs, the key is applied per
> level.

So your key function needs to accept the whole index and return an index rather than scalar values.

As I write this Andrej has just supplied an example of how this is done in his answer.

Depending on your coding style you might prefer to avoid the lambda and use a named function

```
def sort_by_before_underscore(ix):
    return (ix.str.split("_")
    .str[0]
    .astype(int))

df = df.sort_index(
    key=sort_by_before_underscore
)
```